# Put ListView on CardView without the ListViews header

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

My ListView has an header, with a lot of stuff in it. This stuff is arranged on two CardViews. Now there should be the rest of the ListView on a third CardView, but I dont see a way to achieve this.
When I simply put an CardView around the ListView, everything is on that CardView, but just the third part, the actual List, should be on that Card.
Anybody an Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Make one xml for header, that contain both the card view and separately add that xml as header to your listview.

Comment: Yes, but than how to put the rest of the listview on a cardview?